# How to perform more complex spatial joins with GeoDataFrames?

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, spatial-query

Given two `GeoDataFrame`s, `g1`, `g2`, I want to get all the rows from `g1` which do not *intersect* any rows from `g2`, or only *touch* them.

For this there are some operations which I am missing in the interface:

- (Left) Semi-Join (only keep data from left side after filtering it by binary predicate with right side)
- (Left) Anti-Join (only keep rows that do not fulfill the binary predicate with any of the rows of the right side)
- Logical operators (OR, NOT, AND, etc.) for the binary predicate.
- Unique (do not duplicate left rows on multiple hits)

I would like to be able to write a query like this:

```py
result = g1.sjoin(g2, how="left-anti-semi", predicate="intersects & ~touches")
```

Or at least:

```py
intersect_but_not_touch = lambda left_shape, right_shape: left_shape.intersects(right_shape) and not left_shape.touches(right_shape)
joined = g1.sjoin(g2, how="left", predicate=intersect_but_not_touch)
result = joined.query('right_index != right_index') # anti-join.
```

But I did not see any way to combine predicates, or to pass a function as a predicate. Is there any way to do any of that with `sjoin` or do we have to do that "manually"?

This is the solution I have got so far, but this is far too complicated:

```py
# Duplicate geometry column so it remains after sjoin.
g2["right_geometry"] = g2["geometry"]
intersect = g1.sjoin(g2, how="left")
# right index is Nan, no intersection found.
dont_intersect = intersect.query("right_index != right_index") # anti-join
intersect = intersect.query("right_index == right_index")
# row-wise "touches" predicate.
intersect["just_touch"] = intersect.touches(intersect["right_geometry"])
intersect_but_just_touch = intersect.groupby(intersect.index).filter(
    lambda x: x.just_touch.all()
)
result = pd.concat([dont_intersect, intersect_but_just_touch])
```

Comment: there's certainly no way to combine predicates like this. you could do the sjoin with each op separately and then combine the matches. but from your description `"intersects & (~touches)"` it sounds like you might be asking about `contains`? `A.contains(B)` returns true if B is wholly within A and they do not have any boundary points in common. see the [shapely docs on binary predicates](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#relationships) and the [paper they reference](https://giswiki.hsr.ch/images/3/3d/9dem_springer.pdf).

Comment: @MichaelDelgado no,  `intersects & (~touches)` is not equivalent to  `contains`. For example, `a.intersects(b) and not a.touches(b)` could apply also in some cases where the exterior of a intersects with the interior of b. Obviously `contains` could not. The difference between `intersects & ~touches` and just `intersects` is that `intersects` alone also applies when the interiors of the two shapes do not intersect, and my predicate only applies when the interiors intersect. There are also ways to express this using other predicates, but they still require some logical operators.

Comment: ok yep that's fair. so then you'll have to do some postprocessing on the results of each predicate to convert them into a boolean mask and then use the logical operators you need to get the joint mask.